# client_id and client_secret is missing or has an incorrect value

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I am using react-native-app-auth library and passing in grant type: authorization code with PKCE and client credentials

```
const config = {    
    issuer: "***",
    clientId: "***",
    clientSecret: '***',
    redirectUrl: '***:/oauthredirect',
    additionalParameters: {},
    scopes: ['***']
}

const newAuthState = await authorize(config);
```

Able to enter credentials and redirect to react native app but getting error of **client_id and client_secret is missing or has an incorrect value**

client_id, client_secret and scope are correct. And scope, redirectUrl are registered on server.

Comment: Do check in Fiddler and see what is actually sent from the browser to the token server

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth

clientAuthMethod - (string) ANDROID Client Authentication Method. Can be either basic (default) for Basic Authentication or post for HTTP POST body Authentication

passing clientAuthMethod as post worked for me.